# Creating and pushing to an array with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make a messaging system that writes each message to a mongo entry.  I'd like the message entry to reflect the user that sends the message, and the actual message content.  This is the message schema:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    messages: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

And this is where I either create a new entry, or append to an existing one:

```
Message.findOne({ id: chatId }).then(message => {
            if(message){
                Message.update.push({ messages: { 'name': user.name, 'message': user.message } })
            } else {
                const newMessage = new Message(
                    { id: chatId },
                    { push: { messages: { 'name': user.name, 'message': user.message } } }
                )
                newMessage
                    .save()
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
        })
```

I'd like the end result to look something like this:

```
id: '12345'
messages: [
 {name: 'David', message: 'message from David'},
 {name: 'Jason', message: 'message from Jason'},
 etc.
]
```

Is something like this possible, and if so, any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: You've created an "unbounded array" problem for yourself. Your array is designed to grow indefinitely. Eventually, your array will grow past the maximum document size, effectively breaking your application.

Comment: Gotcha.  Is there a better way to store message entries in a chat?

Comment: Would it be better to just make a new mongo entry for each message you think?

Comment: That might work, but that's a fairly broad question. Might be worth trying, to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This questions contains lots of topics (in my mind at least). I really want to try to break this questions to its core components:

### Design

As David noted (first comment) there is a design problem here - an ever-growing array as a sub document is not ideal (please refer to this [blog post](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/) for more details).

On the over hand - when we imagine how a separate collection of messages will looks like, it will be something like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('...') // how do I identify the message
channel_id: 'cn247f9' // the message belong to a private chat or a group
user_id: 1234 // which user posted this message
message: 'hello or something' // the message itself
```

Which is also not that great because we are repeating the channel and user ids as a function of time. This is why the [bucket pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern) is used

So... what is the "best" approach here?

### Concept

The most relevant question right now is - *"which features and loads this chat is suppose to support?"*. I mean, many chats are only support messages display without any further complexity (like searching inside a message). Keeping that in mind, there is a chance that we store in our database an information that is practically irrelevant.

This is (almost) like storing a binary data (such an image) inside our db. we can do this, but with no actual good reason. So, if we are not going to support a full-text search inside our messages, there is no point to store the messages inside our db.. at all

But.. what if we want to support a full-text search? well - who said that we need to give this task to our database? we can easily download messages (using pagination) and make the search operation on the client side itself (while keyword not found, download previous page and search it), taking the loads out of our database!

So.. it seems like that messages are not ideal for storage in database in terms of size, functionality and loads (you may consider this conclusion as a shocking one)

### ReDesign

- Using a hybrid approach where messages are stored in a separated collection with pagination (the bucket pattern supports this as described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1))
- Store messages outside your database (since your are using `Node.js` you may consider using [chunk store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abstract-chunk-store)), keeping only a reference to them in the database itself
- Set your page with a size relevant to your application needs and also with calculated fields (for instances: number of current messages in page) to ease database loads as much as possible

### Schema

```
channels:
  _id: ObjectId
  pageIndex: Int32
  isLastPage: Boolean
  // The number of items here should not exceed page size
  // when it does - a new document will be created with incremental pageIndex value
  // suggestion: update previous page isLastPage field to ease querying of next page
  messages:          
  [
    { userId: ObjectID, link: string, timestamp: Date } 
  ]
  messagesCount: Int32
```

### Final Conclusion

I know - it seems like a complete overkill for such a "simple" question, but - [Dawid Esterhuizen](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/desterhuizen) convinced me that designing your database to support your future loads from the very beginning is crucial and always better than simplifying db design too much

**The bottom line is that the question *"which features and loads this chat is suppose to support?"* is still need to be answered if you intend to desgin your db efficiently** (e.g. to find the Goldilocks zone where your design suits your application needs in the most optimal way)